# zend framework 2/3 collection set custom attributes

Tags: zend-framework2, customization, zend-framework3, zend-form-fieldset, zend-form-collection

Judging by these questions:

[Zend framework 2 loop through elements of element collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31588206/zend-framework-2-loop-through-elements-of-element-collection)

[How to pass an argument to a Zend Form Collection instance & How to set custom Fieldset labels in ZF2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35100826/how-to-pass-an-argument-to-a-zend-form-collection-instance-how-to-set-custom-f)

**I suppose there isn't a good way to customize the elements of a collection.**

As example, having a collection like:

```
//path: MyModule\Form\MyFieldset

public function __construct($name = null) {

    parent::__construct('myFieldset');

    $this->add([
        'name'=>'test',
        'type' => Element\Collection::class,
        'options' => [
            'label' => 'MyCollection',
            'count' => 6,
            'should_create_template' => true,
            'target_element' => new Element\Text()
        ],
    ]);
}
```

Then do something in order to define (**here, into the current class**) custom attributes for each text element and/or autonumbered labels and then output (simply calling the zend helper FormCollection, without any custom view helper):

```
<label>
   <span>text element n° 1</span>
   <input type="text" name="myFielset[test][0]" id='myId_0' alt='input 0' value="">
</label>

<label>
   <span>text element n° 2</span>
   <input type="text" name="myFielset[test][1]" id='myId_1' alt='input 1' value="">
</label>

[...]
```

**Am I wrong?**

(I'm asking that because I've found a nice solution to do that and maybe could be helpful to post it)

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found has something in common with the one provided by Richard Parnaby-King:

> target_element must reference a fieldset.

But instead that setting a clone counter, it extends the `Zend\Form\Fieldset method prepareElement`

**Basic application:**

```
namespace Module\Form;

use Zend\Form\Fieldset;
use Zend\Form\FormInterface; //needed in order to call prepareElement method

class MyFieldset extends Fieldset {


    public function __construct($name = null) {
        parent::__construct($name);

        $this->add([
            'name' => 'question',
            'type' => 'text',
            'attributes' => [
                'alt' => 'input',
            ],
            'options' => [
                'label' => 'Text',
            ],
        ]);

    }//construct

    public function prepareElement(FormInterface $form){

        parent::prepareElement($form);

        $name = $this->getName(); 
        //Do stuff related to this fieldset

        foreach ($this->iterator as $elementOrFieldset) {

           $elementName=$elementOrFieldset->getName()
           //Do stuff related to this fieldset children
        }

    }//prepareElement

}
```

Features:

1. Autonumbering labels and/or attributes
2. Allows conditional assignment of attributes/labels
3. Allows interaction between different elements (ex: passing element A id to element B as target)
4. Works with templates

---

---

Since this solution could be developed in many ways, **I prepared a complete demonstration ready to run and explore**.

*Note: this demonstration isn't the best implementation but a collection of examples which leads to a result. :-)*

This example is meant to run under the default module 'Application' using the prefix 'Bob' in order to avoid conflicts with other files (I imagined someone could already have a file named TestController but I guess nobody have a file called BobController).

Then if you follow the next steps exactly you should be able to run & explore the demonstration without any problem.

The implemantation of the `prepareElement` method into the `BobFieldset` class could appear massive but its' just a matter of comments, spaces and examples. It could be very small depending on your needs.

**STEP 1:**

EDIT file: Application\config\module.config.php

```
//add bob route to router

'router' => [
        'routes' => [

            'bob' => [
                'type' => Literal::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route'    => '/bob',
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => Controller\BobController::class,
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ],
                ],
            ],

            [...]

//add BobController

 'controllers' => [
        'factories' => [
            [...]
            Controller\BobController::class => InvokableFactory::class,
        ],
    ],
```

**STEP 2:**

CREATE file: Application\src\Controller\BobController.php

```
<?php

namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

use Application\Form\BobForm;

class BobController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function __construct(){}

    public function indexAction()
    {

     $form = new BobForm('album');

     $request = $this->getRequest();


     if( $request->isPost()){

       $form->setInputFilter($form->getInputFilter());
       $form->setData($request->getPost());

        if (! $form->isValid()) {
            return ['form' => $form];
        }
     }
     return ['form' => $form];
    }
}
```

**STEP 3:**

CREATE file: Application\src\Form\BobForm.php

```
 <?php

namespace Application\Form;

use Zend\Form\Element;
use Zend\Form\Form;

class BobForm extends Form
{
   private $inputFilter;
    public function __construct($name = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($name);

        $this->setLabel('formBaseFieldset');

        $this->add([
            'name' => 'select',
            'type' => 'select',
            'options' => [
                'label' => 'random element',
                'value_options' => [
                             0 => null,
                             1 => 'someThing',
                             2 => 'someThingElse',
                     ],
            ],
            'attributes' => [
            'value'  => 0,
            ],
        ]);

        $this->add([
            'name' => 'answer',
            'type' => Element\Collection::class,
            'options' => [
                'label'=>'bobFieldset',
                'count' =>3,
                'should_create_template' => true,
                'target_element' => new \Application\Form\BobFieldset ,
            ],
            'attributes' => [
            'id'=>'bob',
            ],
        ]);
        $this->add(array(
             'name' => 'addNewRow',
             'type' => 'button',
             'options' => array(
                 'label' => 'Add a new Row',
             ),
             'attributes' => [
             'onclick'=>'return add_category()',

             ]
         ));

}//construct

    public function getInputFilterSpecification() {
               return array(

            'select' => [
                'validators' => [
                    ['name' => 'NotEmpty'],
                ],  
            ],
        );
    }

}
```

**STEP 4:**

CREATE file: Application\src\Form\BobFieldset.php

```
<?php

namespace Application\Form;

use Zend\Form\Fieldset;
use Zend\Form\FormInterface; //needed in order to call prepareElement method
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterProviderInterface;

class BobFieldset extends Fieldset  implements InputFilterProviderInterface 
{

   private $inputFilter;

    public function __construct($name = null) {

        parent::__construct($name);

        $this->setLabel('bobFieldset: Answer __num__');

        $this->add(array(
             'name' => 'text',
             'type' => 'text',
             'options' => array(
                 'label' => 'Text __num__',
             ),
             'attributes' => [
             'customAttribute'=>' -> ', //see below

             ]
         ));

        $this->add(array(
             'name' => 'optionsButton',
             'type' => 'button',
             'options' => array(
                 'label' => 'Options',
             ),
             'attributes' => [
             'data-dialog-target'=>'options', //sub fieldset name
             'class'=>'options',
             ]
         ));

        $this->add( new \Application\Form\BobSubFieldset('options'));
    }

   public function prepareElement(FormInterface $form)
    {

        /*--->here we're looping throug the collection target_element(instance of BobFieldset)<---*/

        //Leave untouched the default naming strategy
        parent::prepareElement($form);



        //output: (string) 'answer[$i]' -> BobFieldset's clone name attribute
        //Note: $i corresponds to the instance number
        $name = $this->getName();   //var_dump($name);

        //output: array(0=>'answer',1=>$i)
        $sections = $this->splitArrayString($name); //var_dump($sections);

        //output: (string) $i ->When the collection's option 'should_create_template' is setted to true, the last one will be: (string) '__index__'
        $key=end($sections);  //var_dump($key);

        //output (string) 'answer_$i' -> I guess this could be the easyest way to handle ids (easy to manipulate, see below)
        $string=implode('_',$sections); //var_dump($string);


        //Just because a label like 'answer number 0' is ugly ;-)
        $keyPlus=(is_numeric($key)) ? $key+1 : $key;  //var_dump($keyPlus);

        //Since we're using different placeholders:
        //Predefined __index__: used for names ($key)
        //__num__: used for labels ($keyplus)
        //Then we need this control to avoid replacements between placeholders(check below)
        $isTemplate=($keyPlus==$key) ? true : false;


        if(!$isTemplate){
          //get the label of the current element(BobFieldset clone) and replace the placeholder __num__ (defined above) with the current key (+1)
          $label = str_replace('__num__',($keyPlus),$this->getLabel());
          $this->setLabel($label); //var_dump($this->getLabel());
        }
        /*--->From here we're looping throug the target_element (BobFieldset) children<---*/
        foreach ($this->iterator as $elementOrFieldset) {

            //output: (string) 'answer[$i][elementName]'
            //answer[0][text]
            //answer[0][optionsButton]
            //answer[0][options]
            //answer[1][text]
            //...
            $elementName=$elementOrFieldset->getName();//var_dump($elementName);

            //Example: get specific element and OVERWRITE an autonumbered label
            $sections = $this->splitArrayString($elementName);
            $trueName=end($sections);
            if($trueName=='text' && !$isTemplate){
              $elementOrFieldset->setLabel('Input '.$keyPlus);
            }

           //Example2: get specific element via custom attribute
           //Note: when an attribute isn't listed into the Zend\Form\View\Helper\AbstractHelper's $validGlobalAttributes (array) it will be automatically removed on render
           //global attributes data-? will be rendered
           if($target=$elementOrFieldset->getAttribute('customAttribute')){
             $label=$elementOrFieldset->getLabel();
             $elementOrFieldset->setLabel($label.$target);
             }

           //Reference another element as target for a javascript function
           //button 'optionsButton' will have an attribute containing the id of the relative element 'options' (BobSubFieldset)
           //Alternatives:
           //1) work only with javascript & DOM 
           //2) set a javascript call directly: $elementOrFieldset->setAttribute('onclick','return doSomething();'); check BobForm 'addNewRow' button
           if($target=$elementOrFieldset->getAttribute('data-dialog-target')){
             $elementOrFieldset->setAttribute('data-dialog-target',$string.'_'.$target);
           }

           //set id for jqueryui dialog function. This id corresponds to the target setted above
           //The attribute data-transform will be used as jquery selector to create the dialogs
           if($elementOrFieldset->getAttribute('data-transform')=='dialog'){
             $id = str_replace(['[', ']'],['_', ''],$elementName);
             $elementOrFieldset->setAttribute('id',$id);

             //Set and autonumbering the dialog title
             if(!$isTemplate){
               $title = str_replace('__num__',($keyPlus),$elementOrFieldset->getAttribute('title'));
               $elementOrFieldset->setAttribute('title',$title);
             }
           }


        }//foreach

    }

    public function splitArrayString($string){

    return preg_split('/\h*[][]/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    }


    public function getInputFilterSpecification() {
               return array(

            'text' => [
                'validators' => [
                    ['name' => 'NotEmpty'],
                ],  
            ],
        );
    }
 }
```

**STEP 5:**

CREATE file: Application\src\Form\BobSubFieldset.php

```
<?php

namespace Application\Form;

use Zend\Form\Fieldset;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterProviderInterface;

class BobSubFieldset extends Fieldset  implements 
InputFilterProviderInterface {

   private $inputFilter;

    public function __construct($name = null) {
         parent::__construct($name);

              $this->setLabel('bobSubFieldset');
              $this->setattribute('data-transform','dialog');
              $this->setattribute('title','Options for answer __num__');


         $this->add(array(
             'name' => 'first',
             'type' => 'text',
             'options' => array(
                 'label' => 'firstOption',
             ),
             'attributes' => [

             ]
         ));
         $this->add(array(
             'name' => 'second',
             'type' => 'text',
             'options' => array(
                 'label' => 'secondOption',
             ),
             'attributes' => [

             ]
         ));
                $this->add(array(
             'name' => 'third',
             'type' => 'text',
             'options' => array(
                 'label' => 'thirdOption',
             ),
             'attributes' => [

             ]
         ));

    }

    public function getInputFilterSpecification() {
        return array();
    }
}
```

**STEP 6 (last):**

CREATE file: Application\view\application\bob\index.phtml

Note: here I added all the external js/css I used, you may already have some in your layout.

```
<?php

$script=
"$(document).ready(function(){

 $( '#bobContainer' ).on('click','button.options', function () {

    //Retrieve the target setted before...
    id=$(this).attr('data-dialog-target');
     $('#'+id).dialog('open');


    return false;
  });

 //We need a custo event in order to detect html changes when a new element is added dynamically
 $( '#bobContainer' ).on( 'loadContent', function() {

     //We need this because by default the dialogs are appended to the body (outside the form)
     $('fieldset[data-transform=dialog]').each(function (index) {

     $(this).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        appendTo:$(this).parent(),
        modal: true,
        height: 250,
        width: 450,
        buttons: {

        Ok: function() {
          $(this).dialog( 'close' );
        }
      },



    });
    });
  });


 $( '#bobContainer' ).trigger( 'loadContent');
}); //doc/ready

function add_category() {

var currentCount = $('#bob > fieldset').length;
var template = $('#bob > span').data('template');

template = template.replace(/__index__/g, currentCount);
template = template.replace(/__num__/g, (currentCount+1));

$('#bob').append(template).trigger( 'loadContent');

return false;
}
";
$this->headScript()
            ->appendFile("https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js",'text/javascript',array('integrity' => 'sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=','crossorigin'=>'anonymous'))
            ->appendFile("https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js")
            ->appendScript($script, $type = 'text/javascript', $attrs = array());
$this->headLink()
            ->appendStylesheet('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css')
            ->appendStylesheet('https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css');


echo $this->headScript();
echo $this->headLink();

$title = 'Custom Collection Attributes';
$this->headTitle($title);

echo'<h1>'.$this->escapeHtml($title).'</h1>';
echo'<div class="container" id="bobContainer">';


$form->prepare();
echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
echo $this->formCollection($form);

$form->add([
            'name' => 'submit',
            'type' => 'submit',
            'attributes' => [
                'value' => 'Go',
                'id'    => 'submitbutton',
                'class'=>'btn btn-success',
            ],
        ]);

$submit = $form->get('submit');

echo '<br>'.$this->formSubmit($submit);

echo $this->form()->closeTag();

echo'</div>';
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image: screenshot1]
[image: screenshot2]

[image: screenshot3]

---

**EDIT**
I noticed a little issue: when an element is created from template, the dialogs of the older elements became unaccessible. This is related to the jquery dialog option `modal: true`. Probably there is a fix but since the main argument regards Zend...just remove that option.

Answer (score 1):

I just realized there is another good and somehow more flexible solution: extending the collection element (why didn't I tink about it before?).

The main advantage in this approach is that there's no need to split the element's name: the "clone number" (`[0],[1],...`) is directly accessible.

**Features:**

1. Autonumbering labels and/or attributes
2. Allows conditional assignment of attributes/labels
3. Allows interaction between different elements (limited, see the issues below)
4. Works with templates (using placeholders -> [read more](https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-form/collections/#adding-new-elements-dynamically)) and there's no need to check if the index is a number (that was an issue of my other solution)
5. The target_element could be a simple element, **there's no need** to implement `Zend/Form/Fieldset`

**Issues:**

1. Set IDs could be problematic since (2)
2. from the extended script there's no way to access to the final element's name (ex:
   `fieldset[subfieldset][0][elementName]`) since it will be hierarchically builded later.

   ---

**How it works:**

**1. The extended Collection**

```
//file: Application\src\Form\Element\ExtendedCollection.php
<?php

namespace Application\Form\Element;

use Zend\Form\Element\Collection;

class ExtendedCollection extends Collection
{
    protected $autonumbering_callback = false;
    protected $autonumbering_callback_options = [];  

    public function setOptions($options)
    {
        parent::setOptions($options);

        if (isset($options['autonumbering_callback'])) {
            $this->autonumbering_callback=(isset($options['autonumbering_callback'][0])) ? $options['autonumbering_callback'][0] : $options['autonumbering_callback'];
            $this->autonumbering_callback_options=(isset($options['autonumbering_callback'][1])) ? $options['autonumbering_callback'][1] : [];
        }

        return $this;
    }

    protected function addNewTargetElementInstance($key)
    {

        //Original instructions
        $this->shouldCreateChildrenOnPrepareElement = false;

        $elementOrFieldset = $this->createNewTargetElementInstance();
        $elementOrFieldset->setName($key);

        $this->add($elementOrFieldset);

        if (! $this->allowAdd && $this->count() > $this->count) {
            throw new Exception\DomainException(sprintf(
                'There are more elements than specified in the collection (%s). Either set the allow_add option ' .
                'to true, or re-submit the form.',
                get_class($this)
            ));
        }

        //Callback
        if ($this->autonumbering_callback && method_exists(...$this->autonumbering_callback) && is_callable($this->autonumbering_callback)){
          call_user_func_array($this->autonumbering_callback,[$elementOrFieldset,$key,$this->autonumbering_callback_options]);
        }

        return $elementOrFieldset;
    }

}
```

**2. The Target element (here is a fieldset but could be a simple element)**

```
//file: Application\src\Form\BobFieldset.php
<?php

namespace Application\Form;

use Zend\Form\Fieldset;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterProviderInterface;

class BobFieldset extends Fieldset  implements InputFilterProviderInterface {

   private $inputFilter;

    public function __construct($name = null) {

        parent::__construct($name);

        $this->setLabel('Answer __num__');
        $this->setAttributes([
                             'title'=>'title no __num__',
                             'data-something'=>'custom attribute no __num__',
                             ]);


        $this->add(array(
             'name' => 'text',
             'type' => 'text',
             'options' => array(
                 'label' => 'Text',
             ),
         ));

         $this->add(array(
             'name' => 'text2',
             'type' => 'text',
             'options' => array(
                 'label' => 'Text',
             ),
         ));

         $this->add(array(
             'name' => 'text3',
             'type' => 'text',
             'options' => array(
                 'label' => 'Text',
             ),
         ));
    }

    public function getInputFilterSpecification() {
        return array(/*...*/);
    }

}//class
```

**3. The Form (with some example of callback)**

```
//file: Application\src\Form\BobForm.php
<?php

namespace Application\Form;

use Zend\Form\Form;
use Zend\Form\Fieldset; //needed for myCallback3
use Application\Form\Element\ExtendedCollection;

class BobForm extends Form
{
   private $inputFilter;
    public function __construct($name = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($name);


        $this->add([
            'name' => 'answer',
            'type' => ExtendedCollection::class,
            'options' => [
                'count' =>3,
                'should_create_template' => true,
                'target_element' => new \Application\Form\BobFieldset2 ,
                'autonumbering_callback'=>[
                                           [$this,'myCallback'],
                                           ['attributes'=>['title','data-something'],'whateverYouWant'=>'something',]
                                          ],
                ],
        ]);
    }

    public function myCallback($elementOrFieldset, $key, $params){

      foreach($params['attributes'] as $attr){
        $autoNumAttr=str_replace('__num__',($key),$elementOrFieldset->getAttribute($attr));
        $elementOrFieldset->setAttribute($attr,$autoNumAttr);
      }//foreach

      $label = str_replace('__num__',($key+1),$elementOrFieldset->getLabel());
      $elementOrFieldset->setLabel($label);
    }

    public function myCallback2($elementOrFieldset, $key, $params){

      $char='a';
      foreach(range(1,$key) as $i) {
        if($key>0){$char++;}
      }
      $elementOrFieldset->setLabel('Answer '.$char);
    }

    public function myCallback3($elementOrFieldset, $key, $params, $isChild=null){

      if(!$isChild){$elementOrFieldset->setLabel('Answer '.($key+1));}
      else{$elementOrFieldset->setLabel($key);}

      //don't forget: use Zend\Form\Fieldset;
      if($elementOrFieldset instanceof Fieldset && !$isChild){
        $char='a';
        foreach($elementOrFieldset as $item){
          $this->myCallback3($item,($key+1 .$char++.') '),null,1);
        }
      }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

without the `autonumbering_callback` option:
[image: without the autonumbering_callback option]

using `myCallback`:
[image: using myCallback]

using `myCallback2`:
[image: using myCallback2]

using `myCallback3`:
[image: using myCallback3]

Answer (score 0):

`target_element` must reference a fieldset. This can be either a new instance within the form where the collection is, or a class name.

For example:

```
$fieldset = new Fieldset();
$fieldset->add([
    'name' => 'some_field_name',
    'type' => 'text',
]);
$this->add([
    'name'=>'test',
    'type' => Element\Collection::class,
    'options' => [
        'label' => 'MyCollection',
        'count' => 6,
        'should_create_template' => true,
        'target_element' => $fieldset
    ],
]);
```

or

```
$this->add([
    'name'=>'test',
    'type' => Element\Collection::class,
    'options' => [
        'label' => 'MyCollection',
        'count' => 6,
        'should_create_template' => true,
        'target_element' => '\Namespace\Form\MyTextFieldset',
    ],
]);
```

In terms of customising the label for each input, I have not yet found a way to do that.

Not too sure of the inner workings of how the collection works, but I suspect it creates as many new instances of `target_element` as required. In terms of just adding a number to the label (or arbitrary attribute) you could do a fieldset class with a static property that starts with `1`, add it to your label and increment its value?

For example:

```
namespace Module\Form;
use Zend\Form\Fieldset;

class MyFieldset extends Fieldset {
    public static $instance_count = 1;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->add([
            'name' => 'question',
            'type' => 'text',
            'attributes' => [
                'alt' => 'input' . MyFieldset::$instance_count,
            ],
            'options' => [
                'label' => 'Text element No ' . MyFieldset::$instance_count,
            ],
        ]);
        MyFieldset::$instance_count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've submitted another (I believe better) solution. Please check it out and give me your opinion.